# Tomcat Application Deployment in IntelliJ Idea Doesn't Compile Source Files

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, tomcat8

I am working witrh the following environment:

- IntelliJ Idea 2017.1.2
- Tomcat 8.0.43
- Gradle 3.5

I have created a Gradle project with a `server` sub-module, and I am trying to deploy this application with IntelliJ Idea.

The problem is that when running the application. it seems the Idea doesn't completely deploy the application: No class files are generated and the application is unable to start.
Only when I manually run `gradle war` task, the application is deployed, but code changes don't get redeployed and I need to tun the task each time again.

This has never happened and until now everything worked well.
Looking in S.O. and other online resources showed me that apparently all my configurations are correct:
`build.gradle` code of the server module:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

dependencies{
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng
  testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.10'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all
  testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api
  compile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs
  compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs', version: '3.1.9'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider
  compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs', name: 'jackson-jaxrs-json-provider', version: '2.8.5'
  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice
  compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '4.1.0'
  compile project(':core')
  compile project(':core-api')

}

test{
  useTestNG()
}
```

The error I get when I start Tomcat (notes the SEVERE lines at the end):

```
/home/guy/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
[2017-05-12 11:50:57,164] Artifact Gradle : com.navnplay : server.war (exploded): Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
12-May-2017 11:50:57.760 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.43
12-May-2017 11:50:57.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 28 2017 14:42:59 UTC
12-May-2017 11:50:57.762 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.43.0
12-May-2017 11:50:57.765 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
12-May-2017 11:50:57.765 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.4.0-72-generic
12-May-2017 11:50:57.765 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
12-May-2017 11:50:57.765 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
12-May-2017 11:50:57.765 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_131-b11
12-May-2017 11:50:57.765 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
12-May-2017 11:50:57.765 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/guy/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_navnplay_2
12-May-2017 11:50:57.766 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43
12-May-2017 11:50:57.766 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/guy/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_navnplay_2/conf/logging.properties
12-May-2017 11:50:57.767 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
12-May-2017 11:50:57.767 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
12-May-2017 11:50:57.767 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
12-May-2017 11:50:57.767 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
12-May-2017 11:50:57.770 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
12-May-2017 11:50:57.770 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
12-May-2017 11:50:57.770 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
12-May-2017 11:50:57.770 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
12-May-2017 11:50:57.770 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/guy/tomcat/endorsed
12-May-2017 11:50:57.770 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/guy/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_navnplay_2
12-May-2017 11:50:57.770 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/guy/tomcat
12-May-2017 11:50:57.770 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/guy/tomcat/temp
12-May-2017 11:50:57.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /home/guy/idea-IU-171.3780.107/bin:/home/guy/idea-IU-171.3780.107/bin:/home/guy/idea-IU-171.3780.107/bin:/home/guy/idea-IU-171.3780.107/bin:/home/guy/idea-IU-171.3780.107/bin::/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
12-May-2017 11:50:58.001 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-May-2017 11:50:58.021 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
12-May-2017 11:50:58.026 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12-May-2017 11:50:58.030 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
12-May-2017 11:50:58.034 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 702 ms
12-May-2017 11:50:58.065 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
12-May-2017 11:50:58.065 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.43
12-May-2017 11:50:58.070 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-May-2017 11:50:58.079 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12-May-2017 11:50:58.091 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 57 ms
Connected to server
[2017-05-12 11:50:58,472] Artifact Gradle : com.navnplay : server.war (exploded): Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
12-May-2017 11:50:59.401 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
12-May-2017 11:50:59.416 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
12-May-2017 11:50:59.422 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/navnplay] startup failed due to previous errors
[2017-05-12 11:50:59,441] Artifact Gradle : com.navnplay : server.war (exploded): Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
12-May-2017 11:51:08.073 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/docs
12-May-2017 11:51:08.114 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/docs has finished in 41 ms
12-May-2017 11:51:08.114 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/examples
12-May-2017 11:51:08.249 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/examples has finished in 135 ms
12-May-2017 11:51:08.249 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/ROOT
12-May-2017 11:51:08.261 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/ROOT has finished in 12 ms
12-May-2017 11:51:08.261 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/manager
12-May-2017 11:51:08.298 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/manager has finished in 37 ms
12-May-2017 11:51:08.298 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/host-manager
12-May-2017 11:51:08.319 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/guy/apache-tomcat-8.0.43/webapps/host-manager has finished in 21 ms
```

And the exception itself (The exception is thrown because the class isn't actually compiled and deployed):

```
12-May-2017 11:50:59.415 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class com.navnplay.web.di.DIContextListener
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.navnplay.web.di.DIContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1696)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:484)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

12-May-2017 11:50:59.416 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

The server configurations:
[image: Server Configuration]

The deployment configuration:
[image: The Deployment Configuration]

You can see in the following image that the deployment only deployed the the external libraries but none of the generated code I have developed:
[image]

Comment: Would you consider using Gradle cargo, tomcat or jetty plugin instead of running inside IntelliJ? That way you can just run and debug straight from command line or IntelliJ Gradle plugin.

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:
After manually cleaning **ALL** Idea and Gradle generated files, and rebuilding the project, it seems that the project has started working again.

Specifically I believe that the problem was at the `.gradle` library:
After moving from Gradle 3.2 to 3.5, there was still a 
`.gradle/3.2` directory that probably messes things up.